# SQL query in Access - summing populations which may move to different buildings

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Essentially I have School enrollment populations which occupy buildings but are not permanently tied to them. Over a 10 year period the school may move to another building, and multiple schools may occupy the building at the same time. I want to know the total population of the building per year with those changing conditions.

I have 3 tables to work with, the 10 year School enrollments "EnrollProjTest" (fields: School number, SY2014, SY2015, etc.), the current building location of the school "ProgBuild" (fields: School number, building number), and a table indicating the anticipated school movements "ProgMoveBuild" (fields: School number, Year of move, Building Number).

My first thought was to create a grid which contained the program number, then per year the building number it occupies and the enrollment of the program. Then create, per year, the sum of the the enrollments per building. Here is what that code looks like:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT BLDG2014, SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2014)AS Enroll2014,
DISTINCT BLDG2015, SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2015)AS Enroll2015,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2016)AS Enroll2016,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2017)AS Enroll2017,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2018)AS Enroll2018,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2019)AS Enroll2019,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2020)AS Enroll2020,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2021)AS Enroll2021,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2022)AS Enroll2022,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2023)AS Enroll2023,
SUM(EnrollProjTest.SY2024)AS Enroll2024
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProgBuild.PrgNo, IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2014, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2014, EnrollProjTest.SY2014, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2015, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2015, EnrollProjTest.SY2015, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2016, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2016, EnrollProjTest.SY2016, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2017, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2017, EnrollProjTest.SY2017, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2018, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2018, EnrollProjTest.SY2018, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2019, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2019, EnrollProjTest.SY2019, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2020, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2020, EnrollProjTest.SY2020, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2021, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2021, EnrollProjTest.SY2021, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2022, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2022, EnrollProjTest.SY2022, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2023, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2023, EnrollProjTest.SY2023, 
IIF([ProgMoveBuild].[yearmove]<=2024, [ProgMoveBuild].[BldgNo], [ProgBuild].[BldgNo]) AS BLDG2024, EnrollProjTest.SY2024
FROM ((EnrollProjTest LEFT JOIN ProgBuild ON EnrollProjTest.SCHOOL = ProgBuild.PrgNo) LEFT JOIN ProjChangeSRC ON ProgBuild.BldgNo = ProjChangeSRC.BldgNo) LEFT JOIN ProgMoveBuild ON ProgMoveBuild.PrgNo = ProgBuild.PrgNo)
GROUP BY BLDG2014, BLDG2015;`
```

I get a syntax error because I'm grouping by 2 distinct entities. If I group by only 1 of the years, it sums the enrollments based on the building occupied in that year.

Happy to clarify anything I can

Comment: Reformulate your data into a normalised form. For example, change EnrollProj test to separate the year and count into separate columns. Then the queries will be possible for all times and you do not need to enumerate each column separately, but instead use a join with other tables that contain calendar information, or simply group by the year column value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how would I name my columns? Each enrollment is tied to a school and year. If I understand your suggestion, my table would have the following fields: School number, year, Enrollment2015, year, enrollment2016, etc.

Comment: The idea is to have one row in the table for each combination of parameters. Use columns for School, Year, Enrollment. Then, drop the ProgBuild table and only keep the date effective values. Join the tables on both the year and school number. If you want to force values for buildings that may be empty in any year, you need a separate table with all possible years, and introduce outer joins. To avoid that, ensure you record 0 values for years that are not otherwise defined.

Comment: I see now. I will need to try this tomorrow, but one question - could I normalize the data as you suggest dynamically? So start with my base table as is, then sub-query that to output the normalized table you suggest? It is much easier to edit values in the current form than it would be in the form you suggest, as that table would have 1800 rows.

Comment: Pekka - I am having a hard time understanding this. How will I assign a Program to a Building without the ProgBuild table?

Comment: ProgMoveBuild already contains the information, with the addition of a date. Provided your joins include the year, the results will be valid for all time, in the same query.